# Target the <input type="date"> dropdown?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I was trying to scale my input box which accepts a date.

However, on Edge, it also scales the dropdown asking for the date. I don't want this. It works perfectly on Chrome.

A sample code:

```css
#normal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
}

#scaled {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

#scaled:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<input type="date" id="normal" />
<input type="date" id="scaled" />
```

I was thinking of targetting it explicitly and telling it not to scale.
So, how do we target it?

Or, is there any better way to tell it not to scale the dropdown on Edge?

Comment: I found an interesting [related article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/form-inputs-browser-support-issue/) that might help.

Comment: update windows 10 then your edge will behave exactly like chrome :-)

Answer (score 1):

To target edge you can use -ms-ime-align support. edge is only Microsoft browser that support this property. add this part to your css file beside the others.

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
    #scaled {
        transform: scale(1) !important;
    }
}
```

remember that you have to write this css in a separate file, if you use inline in html page, you could get an error.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this targets the input box, not the dropdown. I tried it several times, but this stops the scaling itself. I _want_ the input box to scale, but not the dropdown.

Comment: in Edge date picker shown in other way from chrome. and it is not relevant to scale css. even if you don't write the transform scale, it shown like that.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test your code sample with MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser and I can produce the issue on my side.

It looks like there is an issue with the Edge browser and we can't fix it using code.

As per the information from MDN docs, Scale can create accessibility issues.

> Scaling/zooming animations are problematic for accessibility, as they
>   are a common trigger for certain types of migraine. If you need to
>   include such animations on your website, you should provide a control
>   to allow users to turn off animations, preferrably site-wide.
>
> Also, consider making use of the prefers-reduced-motion media feature
>   — use it to write a media query that will turn off animations if the
>   user has reduced animation specified in their system preferences.

Reference:

[scale() Accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

As suggested in the docs, you can give control to users to turn off animations. As a workaround user can use the MS Edge chromium-browser. Which is working fine.